# JUnit Mockito returning LinkedList instead of ArrayList

Tags: junit, mockito

I have been tasked to figure out why this JUnit Test is failing.  What I have found is that instead of returning an ArrayList (like the getDeligationsForLoggedInUser is SUPPOSED to return, it returns a LinkedList for "userList".

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
public  void test_getDelegationsForLoggedInUser()
{
    String userId="Abcd";
    List<String>  expectedUserList= new ArrayList<String>();
    expectedUserList.add("efghi");
    expectedUserList.add("jklmn");
    expectedUserList.add("opqrs");

    when(namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(anyString(),anyMap(), any(RowMapper.class))).thenReturn(expectedUserList);
    List<String>  userList= workflowProcessDAOImpl.getDelegationsForLoggedInUser(userId);
    verify(namedParameterJdbcTemplate, times(1)).query(sqlCaptor.capture(), namedParameterMap.capture(), rowMapperCaptor.capture());
    assertThat(userList, is(expectedUserList));
    assertThat(sqlCaptor.getValue(), is(SQLConstantsSysConfigV1.getInstance().GET_USERIDS_FOR_DELEGATES));

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Could you provide jUnit failed log? We need to know on which line and by what reason you have failed test..

Answer (score 0):

You mock in this test the method `queryForObject`, but test on the method `query`.

I suppose that your code defines a mock of the function somwhere else, isn't it? It could then simply be the result of a copy/paste operation...

Comment: :(  I changed it to queryForObject....  and it still passes linked list. back.
But there may be something greater going on here.  The error inside the verify statements comes back:

Wanted but not invoked:
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
   <Capturing argument>,
   <Capturing argument>,
   <Capturing argument>
);

I thought that the above code did have those capturing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. To solve that I replaced **Mockito.anyList()** (if param required is list) and **Mockito.anyLong()** (if param required is long). Example:-

```
 Mockito.when(testService.getData(Mockito.anyLong(),
    Mockito.anyList(), Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(SOME_RESPONSE_DATA);
```